# Magento 2 - best way to install extension

Tags: magento2, extensions

I've made a new extension for my company, while developing everything seems to work properly. But when I've tried to install my extension I encountered some problems. At the beginning I've tried to install it by Web Setup Wizard, in version 2.1.2 I received some errors, log below:

```
[2017-01-11 13:40:11 CET] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has been started 
[2017-01-11 13:40:11 CET] Magento maintenance mode is
enabled. 
[2017-01-11 13:40:11 CET] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has successfully completed 

[2017-01-11 12:41:03 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has started Changed cache status: 
config: 1 -> 0 
layout: 1 -> 0 
block_html: 1 -> 0 
collections: 1 -> 0
reflection: 1 -> 0 
db_ddl: 1 -> 0 
eav: 1 -> 0 
customer_notification: 1 -> 0 
full_page: 1 -> 0 
config_integration: 1 -> 0 
config_integration_api: 1 -> 0 
translate: 1 -> 0 
config_webservice: 1 -> 0

[2017-01-11 12:41:03 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has been successfully completed 
[2017-01-11 12:41:03 UTC] Job "setup:module:disable {"components":[{"name":"Salesmanago_Integration"}]}" has started The following modules have been disabled:
- Salesmanago_Integration

Cache cleared successfully. Generated classes cleared successfully.
Please run the 'setup:di:compile' command to generate classes. Info:
Some modules might require static view files to be cleared. To do
this, run 'module:disable' with the --clear-static-content option to
clear them.

[2017-01-11 12:41:04 UTC] Cleaning generated files... 
[2017-01-11 12:41:05 UTC] Complete! [2017-01-11 12:41:05 UTC] Clearing cache...
[2017-01-11 12:41:05 UTC] Complete! [2017-01-11 12:41:05 UTC] Job "setup:module:disable {"components":[{"name":"Salesmanago_Integration"}]}" has been successfully completed
[2017-01-11 12:41:05 UTC] Job "setup:cache:enable ["config layout block_html collections reflection db_ddl eav customer_notification full_page config_integration config_integration_api translate config_webservice"]" has started 
Changed cache status: 
config: 0 -> 1 
layout: 0 -> 1 
block_html: 0 -> 1
collections: 0 -> 1 
reflection: 0 -> 1 
db_ddl: 0 -> 1 
eav: 0 -> 1
customer_notification: 0 -> 1 
full_page: 0 -> 1 
config_integration: 0 -> 1 
config_integration_api: 0 -> 1 
translate: 0 -> 1 
config_webservice: 0 -> 1

[2017-01-11 12:41:05 UTC] An error occurred while executing job
"setup:cache:enable ["config layout block_html collections reflection
db_ddl eav customer_notification full_page config_integration
config_integration_api translate config_webservice"]": Could not
complete setup:cache:enable ["config layout block_html collections
reflection db_ddl eav customer_notification full_page
config_integration config_integration_api translate
config_webservice"] successfully: Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1
to be string, object given in
/var/www/html/magento-212opt/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php
on line 152 
[2017-01-11 13:42:03 CET] There was an error in previous
Update attempt.
```

I've read that it was connected with some errors in Magento 2, is this true ?

Later I was looking for alternative installation types.

First option:
Copy extension to app/code and add line to etc/config.php

'Salesmanago_Integration' => 1,

And after page reload it was ok on my local machine.

Second Option:
Paste extension to app/code and than run:

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade 

 php bin/magentosetup:static-content:deploy 

 chmod -R 777 var pub/static
```

This one also works on my local machine.

Not the questions, which option is the best? Why Web Wizard doesn't work ?  There is a problem with plugin ?

Comment: best way is to make it a composer package and install it with composer

Comment: But I am looking for user friendly installation. We need to give this plugin to our clients so it should be simple... I guess that not every clients have his IT or knows how to use composer or if they have it. How about options from above ?

Comment: Ideally you'll have both. as composer because it is bullet proof and very fast. but if they don't know how to open the terminal then you should offer them as a zip file too. We receive a lot of extensions as zip files. all you need is to drag and drop the folder in app folder. no need to edit etc/config.php. This will be done automatically by setup:upgrade. but still this needs access to terminal... hmm.. on second thought I don't think a magento2 website can be maintained without doing stuff in the terminal.

Comment: If Magento2 can't be maintained without using terminal, so our clients with this platform should have some IT support to install things. I think zip package will be the best for us.

Comment: Summarizing your reply, adding line to config.php is equivalent to setup:upgrade, so maybe we will stay in terminal and use second option but I need to ask... Is it safe? Setup::Upgrade will check every modules and update if there is a need, second command (static-content:deploy) will refresh cache and static content and last comma will change permissions to directories with cache. It seems to be simple but is it safe ?

Comment: Given how buggy magento2 is now I think nobody can say it is safe. A lot of times I needed access to the terminal to redeploy without doing nothing wrong.

Comment: Yes.. I know, I had a lot of problems during the development of the extension... Oe more question about Web Setup Wizard - can we fix it somehow ? It is a global problem ? Are they going to fix it in the nearest future ? 

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: I really don't know. there are hundreds of issues and they prioritize based on their most important client needs

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks for help, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1
to be string, object given in
/var/www/html/magento-212opt/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php
on line 152
```

This suggests you are passing an object instead instead of the expecting class name.

```
/**
 * Get fully qualified class name
 *
 * @param string $className
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getFullyQualifiedClassName($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    return $className ? '\\' . $className : '';
}
```

This happen to me when I switched from `developer mode` to `production mode`.

I fixed it by deleting the content of `var/di` folder.